# re-assigning shared_ptr from within object pointed to

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, self-reference

consider the following code

```
struct base {
  virtual void bar(std::shared_ptr<base>&) = 0;
};

struct foo1 : base { /* ... */ };

struct foo2 : base {
  void bar(std::shared_ptr<base>&obj)
  {
    // ...
    if(some_condition)
      obj = std::make_shared<foo1>();  // re-assign obj
    // ...
  }
};

std::shared_ptr<base> x = std::make_shared<foo2>();
x->bar(x);                             // last line
```

Does this code envoke UB? (note: the re-assigning of obj will destroy the `this` object of call `foo2::bar` when called from the last line). If no data of `bar` are accessed thereafter, is the code still okay?

An alternative way of coding this would be

```
struct base {
  virtual std::shared_ptr<base> bar(std::shared_ptr<base>) = 0;
};
struct foo1 : base { /* ... */ };

struct foo2 : base {
  std::shared_ptr<base> bar(std::shared_ptr<base> obj)
  {
    // ...
    if(some_condition)
      obj = std::make_shared<foo1>();
    // ...
    return obj;
  }
};

std::shared_ptr<base> x = std::make_shared<foo2>();
x=x->bar(x);
```

which should be safe in any case, shouldn't it? Is the extra copying in this code a performance issue?

---

**edit**. After Chris answer, I had a look at [`shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this), which allows the following alternative implementation

```
struct base : std::enable_shared_from_this<base> {
  virtual std::shared_ptr<base> bar() = 0;
};
struct foo1 : base { /* ... */ };

struct foo2 : base {
  std::shared_ptr<base> bar()
  {
    auto obj = shared_from_this();
    if(some_condition)
      obj = std::make_shared<foo1>();
    // ...
    return obj;
  }
};

std::shared_ptr<base> x = std::make_shared<foo2>();
x=x->bar();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this link points out, it is safe and not UB to `delete this` in a method, even if it is a bit confusing.

[Is it safe to `delete this`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550189/is-it-safe-to-delete-this)

I don't think the extra copying is an issue. To be sure you would have to profile. Absent profiling info, if it were me I would prefer second approach to first b/c it's simpler for the programmer to understand, but it's largely opinion.

You might also want to look into the `shared_from_this` template in C++11, if you want to make it simpler for objects to manipulate shared pointers to themselves and such.

Comment: thanks for reminding me of `shared_from_this`.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited question, i.e. the code using `shared_from_this` -- is this how one should use it?

Comment: sure, I guess even more simply it could be `if (some_condition) { return std::make_shared<foo1>(); } else { return shared_from_this(); }`