# Is it safe to access stack variable after `this` has been deleted

Tags: c++, multithreading

Found similar questions: [Is it safe to `delete this`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550189/is-it-safe-to-delete-this)
I know that it's unsafe to access member variable. Because `this` becomes a dangling pointer after `delete`. But what about stack variable？Clang ASAN does report error if member variable is accessed. But it does not report any problems about stack variable access.

IMHO. Stack is destroyed after the current execution thread is finished. So it is probably safe to access stack variable even if `this` is deleted. Is there any better solution in this scenario? Following is the test case.

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <ratio>
#include <string>
#include <system_error>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::mutex g_iostream_mutex;

class TestDeleteBase {
  int task_num_ = 0;
  std::atomic<int> counter_;

 public:
  virtual void Run() = 0;
  void Init(int task_num) {
    task_num_ = task_num;
    counter_.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  }
  void RunParallel() {
    int local = counter_;
    if (counter_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel) == task_num_ - 1) {
      delete this;
      {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_iostream_mutex);
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " deleted this\n";
      }
      return;
    } else {
      {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_iostream_mutex);
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " not delete \n";
      }
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_iostream_mutex);
      std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Access " << local << '\n';
      std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Still alive\n";
    }
  }
  virtual ~TestDeleteBase() {}
};

class TestDelete : public TestDeleteBase {
  void Run() override {}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  TestDeleteBase* obj = new TestDelete();
  obj->Init(5);
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back(&TestDeleteBase::RunParallel, obj);
  }
  for (auto&& thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
  }
}
```

Comment: Should be safe since it's not a member of the instance, but I can't find where you're accessing the automatically allocated variable. The best candidate seems to be `local`, but it's not used between `delete this` and the next `return`.

Comment: `TestDeleteBase t; t.Init(1); t.RunParallel();` **BOOM** The constructor should be protected and private in derived/final classes or protected with a `private: struct Priv {};`. `TestDeleteBase* obj = new TestDelete(); t->RunParallel();` *BOOM* Why is `Init` not the constructor? Or at least initialize the class to sensible values.

Comment: @user4581301 You are right. The stack variable is `local`. And it's accessed by other threads after `this` is deleted

Comment: @8.8.8.8 How would they access it? You're not storing any reference or pointer to it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is having `counter_` equal to `task_num_ - 1` does not mean all threads are finished. It just mean that the `fetch_add` call has been executed by all threads here. The thing is the `==` in the expression `counter_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel) == task_num_ - 1` is **parsed from left to right**. Thus, the `fetch_add` must be executed before `task_num_ - 1` so the threads must access to the `task_num_` member attribute after the `fetch_add` (especially because of the `memory_order_acq_rel` memory ordering). The point is the attribute can be deleted because the last thread can delete the operation meanwhile (which is very unlikely but still possible).

Besides, `local = counter_` do not guarantee to get the last value so the printing will likely be incorrect. You can extract the correct value by storing the result of `fetch_add` in `local`.

Object self destruction if generally a very bad idea because it is very bug prone as said in the question link. Even when you succeed to make the code work, the code is not easy to maintain: another developer might not consider this issue when modifying the code (or even you several month/years after). The best thing to do is to delay delete and the general solution to self destruction is to **define an entity responsible for the deletion** of the object. In this case, the main function can be responsible for that because it is the one doing the `thread.join`. All threads are guaranteed to be freed after the loop by design.

Comment: Very enlightening on the order of delete operation. Except correctness, Is it safe to access `local` in this example after delete operation has been executed?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, this is safe, because `local` is not an attribute and stored on the stack left unaffected by the `delete this`. Btw, you should be careful about virtual calls because they can access to the vtable of the class referenced by the object so calling a virtual function is not safe after the `delete this` (this looks fine here though).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out virtual function. It's unsafe to call virtual functions after `delete this`. Because `vptr` may not point to the correct `vtable` after object deconstruction.