# How to tell the parent that the thread is done in C++ using pthreads?

Tags: c++, tcp, pthreads

I have a TCP Server application that serves each client in a new thread using POSIX Threads and C++.

The server calls "listen" on its socket and when a client connects, it makes a new object  of class Client. The new object runs in its own thread and processes the client's requests.

When a client disconnects, i want some way to tell my main() thread that this thread is done, and main() can delete this object and log something like "Client disconnected".

My question is, how do i tell to the main thread, that a thread is done ?

Comment: Are these client objects "thread objects" or just objects that run in their own thread?

Comment: Just objects that run in their own thread ..

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way that I can see, is to join the threads.  See [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Joining).  The idea is that on a join call, a command thread will then wait until worker threads exit, and then resume.

Alternatively, you could roll something up with some shared variables and mutexes.

Answer (score 2):

pthreads return `0` if everything went okay or they return `errno` if something didn't work.

```
int ret, joined;
ret = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, connect, (void*) args);
joined = pthread_join(&thread, NULL);
```

If `joined` is zero, the thread is done. Clean up that thread's object.

Comment: No, that's not right. "pthread_create" returns 0 to mean that the thread has been created successfully, it doesn't mean that it's done (or even, in fact, that it has had a chance to run at all).

Comment: My mistake, meant to write pthread_join, don't know what I was thinking

Comment: That's wrong, really. if ret is zero, it means the thread was created successfully and nothing more.

Comment: This *blocks* the calling thread, waiting for the new one to finish. If the listener thread does this, it's stuck and can't serve any more requests. The listener should only do this after it knows the client thread is finished. But that just brings us back to the original question: How do you know when the client thread is finished?

Answer (score 2):

If the child thread is really exiting when it is done (rather than waiting for more work), the parent thread can call `pthread_join` on it which will block until the child thread exits.

Obviously, if the parent thread is doing other things, it can't constantly be blocking on `pthread_join`, so you need a way to send a message to the main thread to tell it to call `pthread_join`. There are a number of IPC mechanisms that you could use for this, but in your particular case (a TCP server), I suspect the main thread is probably a `select` loop, right? If that's the case, I would recommend using `pipe` to create a logical pipe, and have the read descriptor for the pipe be one of the descriptors that the main thread selects from.

When a child thread is done, it would then write some sort of message to the pipe saying "I'm Done!" and then the server would know to call `pthread_join` on that thread and then do whatever else it needs to do when a connection finishes.

Note that you don't *have* to call `pthread_join` on a finished child thread, unless you need its return value. However, it is generally a good idea to do so if the child thread has any access to shared resources, since when `pthread_join` returns without error, it assures you that the child thread is really gone and not in some intermediate state between having sent the "I'm Done!" message and actually having exited.

Comment: @Tyler, I believe you leak resources if you don't either join or detach the thread.

Comment: @Michael You're correct. If you're not going to call join, you should detach.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to implement IPC mechanisms to notify a main thread when other threads are about to terminate, if you want to do something when a thread terminates you should try to let the terminating thread do it itself.

You might look into using [`pthread_cleanup_push()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_cleanup_pop.html) to establish a routine to be called when the thread is cancelled or exits.  Another option might be to use [`pthread_key_create()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_key_create.html) to create a thread-specific data key and associated destructor function.

If you don't want to call `pthread_join()` from the main thread due to blocking, you should detach the client threads by either setting it as option when creating the thread or calling `pthread_detach()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a queue of "thread objects to be deleted", protect access to the queue with a mutex, and then signal a pthread condition variable to indicate that something was available on the queue.

But do you really want to do that? A better model is for each thread to just clean up after itself, and not worry about synchronizing with the main thread in the first place.

Comment: OK. I think the idea with selfcleaning threads is good. But is it OK to call the destructor right from the object itself ?

Comment: Yes, you can call "delete this" from the object itself, provided you follow some rules. For example, the object must not be allocated on the stack, and the main thread is not allowed to refer to the object once it creates the processing thread (because the thread may terminate at any time). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447379/what-is-the-use-of-delete-this

Answer (score 0):

Calling `pthread_join` will block execution of the main thread. Given the description of the problem I don't think it will provide the desired solution.

My preferred solution, in most cases, would be to have the thread perform its own cleanup. If that isn't possible you'll either have to use some kind of polling scheme with shared variables (just remember to make them thread safe, hint:[`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx)), or perhaps some sort of OS dependant callback mechanism. Remember, you want to be blocked on the call to `listen`, so really consider having the thread clean itself up.

Comment: Declaring shared variables as "volatile" does not automatically make them thread safe.  There are many discussions on the Net and SO that explain why that is the case.  Rely on the appropriate synchronization mechanism (mutex, etc) or atomic operation to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it's easy to handle termination of a *given* thread with `pthread_join`. But a weak spot of pthreads is funneling information from several sources into a synchronous stream. (Alternately, you could say its strong spot is performance.)

By far the easiest solution for you would be to handle cleanup in the worker thread. Log the disconnection (add a mutex to the log), delete resources as appropriate, and exit the worker thread without signaling the parent.

Adding mutexes to allow manipulation of shared resources is a tough problem, so be flexible and creative. Always err on caution when synchronizing, and profile before optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you described. After ~300 opened client connections my Linux application was not able to create new thread because pthread_join was never called. For me, usage of pthread_tryjoin_np helped.
Briefly:

- have a map that holds all opened thread descriptors
- from the main thread before new client thread is opened I iterate through map and call pthread_tryjoin_np for each thread recorded in map. If thread is done the result of call is zero meaning that I can clean up resources from that thread. At the same time pthread_tryjoin_np takes care about releasing thread resources. If pthread_tryjoin_np call returns number different from 0 this means that thread is still running and I simply do nothing.

Potential problem with this is that I do not see pthread_tryjoin_np as part official POSIX standard so this solution might not be portable.